# How to return a value that is being set from an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to return an Object of type Movie from this method.

```
public MovieParty getMovie(String id) {
    public Movie movie;

    //Create AsyncTask
    connection = new getMovieTask(new RestObserver() {

        @Override
        public void downloadFinished(String result) {
            try {
                //parse the JSON string here and assign it to movie; 
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    connection.execute(id);

    return movie
}
```

> getMovieTask extends AsyncTask.

I am running `downloadFinihsed()` in `onPostExecute` in the async task. I have read just about everything I can on the matter but I still can't figure out how to properly execute that "`return movie`" as it would not have been assigned yet.

Comment: Why don't you just use a Listener, which is called when the Async Task is finished?

Comment: downloadFinished() is the listener running in post execute but I can't return a Movie object from there...

Comment: getMovie should return movie, which is loaded in getMovieTask right? So to return the movie, the getMovie function would have to wait until the Async Task finishes. Which means it blocks. So it would not make sense to use an Async task this way.

Comment: Pls also check your code. `Movie movie` is declared as public in a function, which seems to be wrong.

Comment: So if I have another class calling that method, and I have to use an AsyncTask to send my http request for a JSON string, what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

A quick Example what you could do:

**Create a custom Listener:**

```
interface MovieLoadListener{
    void onMovieLoaded(Movie movie);
    void onMovieLoadFailed(Exception e);
}
```

**Change your method:**

```
public void loadMovieAsync(String id,final  MovieLoadListener listener) {

//Create AsyncTask
connection = new getMovieTask(new RestObserver() {

    @Override
    public void downloadFinished(String result) {
        Movie movie;

        try {
            // do your parsing stuff

            listener.onMovieLoadFailed(e);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            listener.onMovieLoadFailed(e);
        }
    }
});

connection.execute(id);
}
```

**Call your method:**

```
loadMovieAsync(id, new MovieLoadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMovieLoaded(Movie movie) {
            // do with your movie what you like here
        }

        @Override
        public void onMovieLoadFailed(Exception e) {
             // error handling
        }
    } );
```